MacOS Automator and associated file
Using macOS I have a command line executable that I can, following some advice about using Automator, make usable as an application, with the code:
on run {input, parameters}
    
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script with command "myname"
end tell
    
    return input
end run

where myname (not the real name) is an alias I have to the executable I want to run. That does create an executable I can double-click on.
I then want to associate the extension .myname with that application. Which I can do. But when I double-click on the file it runs my application without any reference to the file. I want to run the executable with a single command line parameter, the name of the file I double clicked on. Which I hope/guess I can do by changing "myname" to something like "myname ???" - but what is the ???

I would think something with parameters, but my AppleScript knowledge is very limited. FWIW, there's a nice app called Platypus that can also do all this, and more: https://sveinbjorn.org/platypus

An Automator application passes the input items to the workflow.  For a Run AppleScript action, those are a list in the input parameter.

Something with parameters would be my guess too. But what something? And want it still to work when double clicking the application not a file. For the moment I'll stick with seeing if the application (Automator) I already have and has done most of the work can be made to go the last mile.

red_menace, OK, but how exactly do I do that? What is ??? (or something else).

An Automator application passes the input items to the workflow.  For a Run AppleScript action, it receives those as a list in the input parameter.  The action can also check for an empty input and put up a choose dialog if the application is just double-clicked.
Note that Terminal's do script command is a string (there is no with property), so you would need to build the full command line statement, for example:
on run {input, parameters} -- example
   if input is {} then set input to (choose file with prompt "Choose file items:" with multiple selections allowed)
   set command to "/bin/ls -l " -- path to command - note that a default $PATH is used
   set args to ""
   repeat with anItem in input -- create an argument string from the input list items
      set args to args & space & quoted form of POSIX path of anItem
   end repeat
   tell application "Terminal"
      activate
      try -- use front window
         do script command & args in front window
      on error -- no window, so use a new one
         do script command & args
      end try
   end tell
   return input -- pass items on to other actions
end run


I'm sorry, but in being helpful, you've complicated matters so that with my limited knowledge I can't actually work out what I want. Which parts are descriptive, which are literal text. I don't prompting for a file, if there's no file the application already knows what to do. I don't need to handle multiple files in input, either we double clicked on a file and there is one, or I double clicked on the application and there isn't. I know I need a new window. I don't know what to include when you say "quoted form of POSIX path of anItem".  I really want the absolute bare bones.

@ChristopherDearlove - Text following -- or # on a line are comments. The input will always be a list, so I just handle that. The shell uses POSIX paths, and quoted form escapes spaces and other special characters in the file name. The only thing you need to change is the command string - I just used ls as an example - the script will create the argument list from the input  items (the repeat statement will be skipped if there aren't any). The choose file statement can be removed if you don't want to use it. Please provide more details if I misunderstood what you are trying to do.
